# Copy folder code doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I want copy the content of `data/data` folder in my sdCard. I tryied in this way but doesn't work:

```
copy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                String comando = "cp -r /data/data/* /sdcard/DataBackup";
                Process checkroot = null;
                String[] rootcheck ={"su","-c"};
                try {
                    checkroot = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(rootcheck);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } finally {

                    if (checkroot != null) {
                        try {
                            Process copy = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }                   
                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(null, MainActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.toastroot), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

So, before i check if the device is rooted and then i can copy or i show a toast that says you don't have root. The problem is that `Process copy = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);` doesn't work and not copy the folder. If i write: `String comando = "cp -r /data/data /sdcard/DataBackup";` it creates the `DataBackup` folder but empty. How can i do it? I already have the permission in the manifest.